Krita 5.2.3: how to change the side of only one end of a line?
I'm very new in Krita.
I would like to know whether is possible or not to draw a line in a vector layer, and than changing the thickness of one side respect the other.
Or, more generally, if the line is composed by several points, if it's possible to determine the thickness at each point.
Note: this is one thing that I normally do in Affinity Designer.

As far as I know, it's not possible to add variable stroke widths to vector strokes in Krita.
However there is a workaround for Krita.  Instead of adding a stroke to a vector path, if you use the Edit Shapes tool to create a closed shape, and use a fill and no stroke, you could simply move and adjust the Bézier curves and nodes manually to achieve such an effect.
Example in Krita

It might be better to do this in actual vector software. Krita is really a raster image editor and as such it only has quite basic vector support.  It's not really fair to compare Krita with Affinity Designer which is an actual vector image editor. If you already have Affinity Designer, and it has this feature, then obviously you can use that.
Other vector software such as Adobe Illustrator has a Width tool for this, and similarly Inkscape (free and open source) has a Power Stroke effect which is similar.
Here's an example showing the Power Stroke effect in Inkscape

